# Drawing over a view and all it's children

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view

I'm trying to apply a visual effect to a viewgroup. My idea is to grab a bitmap of the viewgroup, shrink it down, expand it back up, and draw it over the viewgroup to give it a blocky, low quality effect.

I've got most of the way there using this code:

```
public class Blocker {

    private static final float RESAMPLE_QUALITY = 0.66f; // less than 1, lower = worse quality


    public static void block(Canvas canvas, Bitmap bitmap_old) {
        block(canvas, bitmap_old, RESAMPLE_QUALITY);
    }


    public static void block(Canvas canvas, Bitmap bitmap_old, float quality) {
        Bitmap bitmap_new = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap_old, Math.round(bitmap_old.getWidth() * RESAMPLE_QUALITY), Math.round(bitmap_old.getHeight() * RESAMPLE_QUALITY), true);
        Rect from = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap_new.getWidth(), bitmap_new.getHeight());
        RectF to = new RectF(0, 0, bitmap_old.getWidth(), bitmap_old.getHeight());
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap_new, from, to, null);
    }
}
```

I simply pass in the canvas to draw on and a bitmap of what needs to be scaled down+up and it works well.

```
public class BlockedLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {

    private static final String TAG = BlockedLinearLayout.class.getSimpleName();


    public BlockedLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        applyCustomAttributes(context, attrs);
        setup();
    }


    public BlockedLinearLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setup();
    }


    private void setup() {
        this.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    }


    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas);
        // block(canvas); If I call this here, it works but no updates
    }


    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // block(canvas); If I call this here, draws behind children, still no updates
    }

    private void block(Canvas canvas) {
        Blocker.block(canvas, this.getDrawingCache());
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is in my viewgroup. If I run the block method in the viewgroup's draw, it draws over everything but doesn't ever update when child views change. I've traced function calls with Log, and the draw method seems to be running, but nothing changes.

I've also tried implementing this in onDraw. This draws the bitmap behind all the children views, and again they aren't updating.

Can anyone explain how I would go about fixing this?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // call block() here if you want to draw behind children
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    // call block() here if you want to draw over children
}
```

And call destroyDrawingCache() and then, buildDrawingCache() each time you change a child.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately this works for drawing over top of all the children, but if the children are updated after the initial draw, the view isn't updated. For example, I've got a linear layout with a single textview that starts at 1 and increments every second. I can see the number counting, but the linearlayout just draws with a 1 and then doesnt change.

Comment: Try calling destroyDrawingCache() and then, buildDrawingCache() each time you change a child.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be working pretty well. I'm going to play around with it a bit, but do you know if there is any way to detect the child change from the parent view? I'd like to be able to have the parent automatically handle all it's children changing, instead of explicitly telling the parent viewgroup to recache everytime I do something.

Comment: Hmmm... I feel like you'll have to override your children's invalidate() and notify the viewGroup to recreate its cache.

Answer (score 1):

`Draw()` method will work well for you.

I'm now trying to make a count time view in a circle shape, when time is passing, the view will reducing his angle. It's used to cover profile photo(a circle shape photo).

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Android API 23, you can use `onDrawForeground(Canvas)` to draw on top of child views: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#onDrawForeground(android.graphics.Canvas)

Unlike `onDraw()` though, be sure to call through to the super class:

```
@Override
public void onDrawForeground(final Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDrawForeground(canvas);
    // Your code here
}
```