# Android - Background transparency sets also transparency on Paint object

Tags: android, canvas, paint

Im creating a custom view (extending Linearlayout) which has as background color: #B3000000 (75% transparency = B3), and now I need to draw something on this view with full color and not with B3/75% transparency.

What I currently have:

```
public class MyCustomObject extends LinearLayout {

    private Paint paint;

    public MyCustomObject(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public MyCustomObject(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public MyCustomObject(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public MyCustomObject(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        View v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.custom_view, this);
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setAlpha(255);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(50);
        setWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
//        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawLine(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight(),paint);
        Timber.e("Drawing...");
    }
}
```

I would like to draw a RED line on top of this view, and at this moment it draw a red line but with a "black layer" on top, instead a vibrante RED color.

Comment: Whatever is in the `custom_view` layout is being inflated into your custom `LinearLayout`, and it will be in front of whatever you draw to the custom `View`'s `Canvas`. I would guess it's that that's dimming your color.

Comment: @MikeM. how would i draw on top? I would expect to draw on top of LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13346589/drawing-over-a-view-and-all-its-children)

```
@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // draw here if you want to draw behind children
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    // draw here if you want to draw over children
}
```

Comment: Ah, yeah, I didn't think of that. Nice find. Jeez, I've even written a custom `ViewGroup` that utilized that method before. Can't believe I didn't think of that. My bad. Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: Thanks for the help anyway :)